# does this exercise have an error in van Dalen's Logic and Structure?

Tags: logic

this problem is from the section about the completeness of propositional logic with natural deduction proof system.

2.5.10. Show: $\mathrm{Cons}(\Gamma)=\lbrace\sigma\mid\Gamma\vdash\sigma\rbrace$ is maximally consistent $\Leftrightarrow$ $\Gamma$ is complete.

I think the proof of left-to-right side is possible but the converse is impossible, because the auther defined the concept of complete set of propositions as follows:

$\Gamma$ is complete $:=$ for all (propositions) $\varphi$, either $\Gamma\vdash\varphi$ or $\Gamma\vdash\neg\varphi$.

in this definition, I think $\lbrace\bot\rbrace$ is complete but not consistent.

am I wrong?

Comment: from ex falso, it follows that for any P, bottom implies P and -P. So check to see if this satisfies completeness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have copied the definitions correctly from van Dalen, then you are correct. There are two ways to fix this, and which way to go is a matter of taste:

1. Change the definition of "complete" to "for all $\varphi$, either $\Gamma\vdash \varphi$ or $\Gamma\vdash \lnot \varphi$, but not both" [it's possible that when van Dalen wrote "either...or", he had this exclusive or in mind]. Or, equivalently, to "$\Gamma$ is consistent, and for all $\varphi$, $\Gamma\vdash \varphi$ or $\Gamma\vdash \lnot \varphi$. Then consistency is built into the definition of completeness, and the problem statement is true.
2. Keep the definition of complete as it is, and change the problem statement to "Show $\mathrm{Cons}(\Gamma) = \{\sigma\mid \Gamma\vdash \sigma\}$ is maximally consistent $\Leftrightarrow$ $\Gamma$ is complete and consistent."

My preferred fix is 1, since this matches the fact that ultrafilters on Boolean algebras are assumed to be proper. Then complete theories correspond to ultrafilters on the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra, and the problem statement corresponds to the equivalence "$U$ is a maximal (proper) filter $\Leftrightarrow$ $U$ is an ultrafilter."